# views aggregation - number of results per group

Tags: views

I have a content type - lets say favorite color - where you can choose blue, green, red ....

- One node of favorite color has red
- Another node of favorite color has green
- Another node of favorite color has again red

and do so on

I would like to show in views3.7 the name of the color and how often it occurs:

- red: 10
- green: 6
- blue: 3

How do I do this? I think its aggregation but I cant display the number of each result...

Comment: I'm assuming that the 'favorite color' is a tag or vocabulary term?

Answer (score 3):

If what you're trying to show is the number of nodes tagged with a certain term (I'm assuming that color field is a term, not a select text field), then the following [Drupalwoo tutorial](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/showing-node-count-term-views-listing) has detailed step-by-step instructions on creating a view that shows the number of nodes per term.

Here are the basics - just without the screenshots.

1. Your view should be setup to display taxonomy terms, not nodes.
2. Add a **relationship** that is '`Taxonomy term: Content using <term name>`', in your case the term name will be something like 'Color'
3. Configure the relationship to be required or not: depending on whether you want to show colors even if there are no nodes tagged with that color
4. Select to use **aggregation** in the view's advanced settings
5. Add a node field to this view that is excluded from the display, but is used to count the number of node instances under each term.  I would select the '**Node: nid**' field for this purpose.  Make sure to use the relationship setup above
6. Finally - select '**Count DISTINCT**' as the type of aggregation for this field
7. You'll probably want to style the output a little: in your example you want to use a colon between the term and the count, while in the blog's example above there are parentheses!  Feel free to style however!